# left headlight takes some time to turn on

Tags: honda, electrical, accord, headlight

I have a 2008 Honda Accord.  The last 3 or 4 times I've driven at night I've noticed something strange.  When I first turn on the car only the right headlight turns on... but then after about a minute or so of driving the left turns on.  The bulb itself clearly works so I'm thinking it must be some sort of electrical problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't know what type of bulb the '08 Accord uses (probably an H4?), but I've seen bulbs which have a loose filament which has burned through, but it will reattach itself and create light. The bulb is "technically" bad, but works intermittently. You may want to check the bulb itself for burnt spots or to see if the filament is dangling. If you do take it out, ensure you DO NOT TOUCH the bulb with your bare fingers. Oil from your hands will damage the bulb and kill it quickly (if it is still good).

Comment: I'm assuming these are regular bulbs?  The 2008 Accord didn't have an HID option, right?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 how do I flag this comment as "should be an answer"?

Comment: @SampoSarrala - You can't, but if you like the comment and agree with it, you can uptic it at the left (you'll see an up twiddle and a flag if you hover just to the left of the comment a bit).